# React.js: Why is my variable in useReducer empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass an object containing array to a child component

I've implemented some loading until my state array called `profileModule` is populated

However, the object 'profileModule' being passed contains an empty array

Can anyone enlighten me on what am I missing? Please see code below.

Actual passing of object to child component:

```
var [state, dispatch] = useReducer(layoutReducer, {
    isSidebarOpened: true,
    modules: profileModules,
  });

  if (profileModules && profileModules.length > 0) {
    return (
      <LayoutStateContext.Provider value={state}>
        <LayoutDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
          {children}
        </LayoutDispatchContext.Provider>
      </LayoutStateContext.Provider>
    );
  } else {
    return <LoadingOverlay active={true} spinner={<FadeLoader />} text="" />;
  }
```

As you can see above, in `useReducer` function, I'm trying to pass `modules: profileModules` to a child component

I don't understand why I'm getting value when I console.log it before the actual rendering of page but when its inside `useReducer` I only get empty array

Here is how I populate the value of `profileModule` which comes from an API

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    retrieveProfileDetails();
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (profileDetails.length > 0) {
      const modules = profileDetails.map((module) => module.module);
      setProfileModules(profileModules.concat(modules));
    }
  }, [profileDetails]);

  const retrieveProfileDetails = useCallback(() => {
    const profileListArr = profileList.split(",");
    profileListArr.forEach((profileListArrMap) => {
      ProfileMaintenanceService.retrieveProfileDetails(profileListArrMap).then(
        (response) => {
          setProfileDetails(response.data);
        }
      );
    });
  });
```

Full code:

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useReducer,
  useContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useLayoutEffect,
  useCallback,
} from "react";
import { USER_PROFILE_ID_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE } from "../services/AuthenticationService";
import ProfileMaintenanceService from "../services/ProfileMaintenanceService";
import LoadingOverlay from "react-loading-overlay";
import FadeLoader from "react-spinners/FadeLoader";

var LayoutStateContext = createContext();
var LayoutDispatchContext = createContext();

export {
  LayoutProvider,
  useLayoutState,
  useLayoutDispatch,
  toggleSidebar,
  toggleOffSidebar,
};

function toggleSidebar(dispatch) {
  dispatch({
    type: "TOGGLE_SIDEBAR",
  });
}

function toggleOffSidebar(dispatch) {
  dispatch({
    type: "TOGGLE_OFF_SIDEBAR",
  });
}

function layoutReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "TOGGLE_SIDEBAR":
      return { ...state, isSidebarOpened: !state.isSidebarOpened };
    case "TOGGLE_OFF_SIDEBAR":
      return { ...state, isSidebarOpened: false };
    case "CUSTOMIZE_SIDEBAR":
      return { ...state, isSidebarOpened: false };
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
    }
  }
}

function LayoutProvider({ children }) {
  const profileList = sessionStorage.getItem(USER_PROFILE_ID_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE);

  const [profileDetails, setProfileDetails] = useState([]);
  const [profileModules, setProfileModules] = useState([]);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    retrieveProfileDetails();
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (profileDetails.length > 0) {
      const modules = profileDetails.map((module) => module.module);
      setProfileModules(profileModules.concat(modules));
    }
  }, [profileDetails]);

  const retrieveProfileDetails = useCallback(() => {
    const profileListArr = profileList.split(",");
    profileListArr.forEach((profileListArrMap) => {
      ProfileMaintenanceService.retrieveProfileDetails(profileListArrMap).then(
        (response) => {
          setProfileDetails(response.data);
        }
      );
    });
  });

  var [state, dispatch] = useReducer(layoutReducer, {
    isSidebarOpened: true,
    modules: profileModules,
  });

  if (profileModules && profileModules.length > 0) {
    return (
      <LayoutStateContext.Provider value={state}>
        <LayoutDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
          {children}
        </LayoutDispatchContext.Provider>
      </LayoutStateContext.Provider>
    );
  } else {
    return <LoadingOverlay active={true} spinner={<FadeLoader />} text="" />;
  }
}

function useLayoutState() {
  var context = useContext(LayoutStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useLayoutState must be used within a LayoutProvider");
  }
  return context;
}

function useLayoutDispatch() {
  var context = useContext(LayoutDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useLayoutDispatch must be used within a LayoutProvider");
  }
  return context;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't your state array be `modules` and not `profileModules`? `profileModules` is initially empty, so `state.modules` is initially an empty array. I don't see in `layoutReducer` any handled action that updates the value of `modules`.

Comment: Where should I update the value of `modules`? Isn't it going to get the value of `profileModules` from the state? Specifically, this line: `modules: profileModules,`

Comment: Yes, but the initial state is `[]` from `const [profileModules, setProfileModules] = useState([]);` higher up in the component. The `useLayoutEffect` that `setProfileModules(profileModules.concat(modules));` updates the value of `profileModules` for the *next* render cycle. (*at least that is what it looks like you are trying to do, update the initial state value of `profileModules`, maybe*)

Comment: I see. If that's the case, how can I do the `setProfileModules(profileModules.concat(modules));` part higher up in the component so `modules` would get its value from it? From my understanding, `useLayoutEffect` runs at the same time while rendering

Comment: Maybe also dispatch an action to update `module` in the `useReducer` state. Basically anytime the `useLayoutEffect`'s callback is triggered because `profileDetails` updated, then recompute the modules that are appended and dispatch to update reducer state.

Comment: Could you provide an example please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The initial modules state is `[]` from `const [profileModules, setProfileModules] = useState([]);` higher up in the component. The `useLayoutEffect` that `setProfileModules(profileModules.concat(modules));` updates the value of `profileModules` for the next render cycle. In the first render cycle when the component mounts the value of `profileModules` is only ever able to be what the initial state is from the `useState` hook.

## Solution

Add a new action creator and case to handle updating the `modules` state value when `profileModules` will update

```
function updateModules(dispatch, modules) {
  dispatch({
    type: "UPDATE_MODULES",
    modules,
  });
}

function layoutReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "TOGGLE_SIDEBAR":
      return { ...state, isSidebarOpened: !state.isSidebarOpened };
    case "TOGGLE_OFF_SIDEBAR":
      return { ...state, isSidebarOpened: false };
    case "CUSTOMIZE_SIDEBAR":
      return { ...state, isSidebarOpened: false };

    case "UPDATE_MODULES":
      return { ...state, modules: action.modules }; // <-- reduce new modules into state

    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Update the `useLayoutEffect` that triggers on `profileDetails` updating to dispatch `updateModules`

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (profileDetails.length > 0) {
      const modules = profileDetails.map((module) => module.module);
      setProfileModules(profileModules.concat(modules));

      updateModules(dispatch, modules); // <-- update modules
    }
  }, [dispatch, profileDetails]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was able to fully understand the use of `useReducer` which I think also acts like a `useState` but kind of more complex.

Comment: @iamjpcbau Yeah. It's a model to store and maintain state, but uses a "redux" state machine pattern where actions are dispatched and reducers, which are pure functions, consume the current state and action and compute and return the next state.